# What song is being sung in the bar while George is praying?

Tags: soundtrack, its-a-wonderful-life

When George Bailey first enters Martini's bar in [It's a Wonderful Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/) and prays for help, there is a song being sung in the background that isn't in English (possibly Italian?) and while I can't understand the lyrics, the tone doesn't seem like a Christmas song.

Can anyone identify the song, and does it have any connection to Christmas or to the message of the movie?

Here's a link to the scene: http://youtu.be/vRn26I2Bzd8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is identified in the Youtube comments.  The song is "Vieni Vieni", sung by Adriana Caselotti, (the voice of Snow White.)  Here's [another version on Youtube sung by Tino Rossi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPIf-7LUto0).

Comment: It's also listed [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/soundtrack?ref_=tt_ql_trv_7).

Comment: Is the song in any way related to Christmas, or the theme of the movie, or was it just used as a way to emphasize that Martini was a foreigner?